# Is there anyway to optimize a query consisting union and a long projection list?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

query1--->There is a query consisting of 22-joins(21 Left outer and 1 outer ). And having a long projection list.

UNION

query2-->there is a second query having 21-joins(21 Left outer join)and same set of projection list.

Is there anyway to so that I have to write the projection-list only once and the common joins in query1 and query2. ?

(Note: 21 Left outer joins in both the queries are on the tables)

Comment: Create temp table and then join with that table will make things bit fast

Comment: @MitchWheat, It is oracle

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) states:

> The corresponding expressions in the select lists of the component
>   queries of a compound query must match in number and must be in the
>   same datatype group (such as numeric or character).

This means that you can't get around specifying the projection list only once, as it's a requirement for the `UNION` operator.

There's however some things you can do for the selection part. If both query1 and query2 have common tables/views (outer) joined to them, then you can get them out of the `UNION`, separating this part and joining the common tables/views to it, treating the `UNION` part as a separate `VIEW`.

If you have provided a simplified example of your queries, it would have been better, but here's an example I came up with:

Given this query (supposedly similar to yours):

```
SELECT t0.col1, t2.col2 FROM table0 t0, table2 t2 WHERE t0.col = t2.col(+)
UNION
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.col = t2.col(+);
```

You can replace it with:

```
SELECT q1.col1, t2.col2 FROM
(
  select t0.col1, t0.col FROM table0 t0
  UNION
  select t1.col1, t1.col FROM table0 t1
) q1,
table2 t2
WHERE q1.col = t2.col(+);
```

Cheers